# Determine no. elements in $ \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ where $H$ is the 6 point/5line graph in the shape of H

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, symmetry

Determine the amount of automorphisms in the group $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ where $H$ is the graph with 6 points and five lines in the shape of a capital 'H'. Here is what it should look like, I labeled the points:

[image: The graph $H$]

Now I can clearly see that rotation through the line $12$ and rotation through a vertical axis through the middle will be automorphisms. These can be described by permutation in $S_6$ in the following way:
$$\sigma_1 = (1\ 3)(4\ 6)$$
and
$$\sigma_2 = (1\ 4)(2\ 5)(3\ 6)$$
then we also have point reflection through the middle which is given by:
$$\sigma_3 = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 = (1\ 6)(2\ 5)(3\ 4)$$
Is this all the symmetries of $H$? I am confused because I do not think the answer should be this simple. If I for instance have the permutation $(2\ 5)$ then will the points $2$ and $1$ still be connected meaning the line piece from $2$ to $1$ will be diagonal implying $(2\ 5)$ is not an automorphism or am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the three automorphisms $a=(1,4)(2,5)(3,6), b=(1,3), c=(4,6)$ generate the full automorphism group $Aut(H)$, and that there are thus 8 automorphisms.  In other words, every automorphism can be obtained by effecting a combination of these three.  More specifically, to effect an automorphism, we can choose whether or not to flip about the vertical line in the middle, and there are 2 ways to make that decision. Thereafter, we choose whether or not to flip the first leg (1,3), and there are 2 ways to decide this, and similarly 2 ways for the right leg.  Any permutation of the vertex set which is an automorphism of this graph can be effected by a sequence of these three decisions.   Thus there are exactly 8 automorphisms.  Thus $G:=Aut(H) \le S_6$ has order 8.

To prove there are exactly 8 automorphisms and no others (and more generally, to find the number of elements in a group), we can use the orbit-stabilizer lemma. Given a permutation group $G \le Sym(X)$, to find $|G|$, pick any $x \in X$, and the lemma states that the number of elements in $|G|$ is equal to the size of the orbit of $x$ under the action of $G$ times the size of the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$, i.e. $|G|=|x^G|~|G_x|$.  In our case, let $x$ be the vertex 2.  Then $x$ can be mapped by an automorphism either to itself or to 5, hence the orbit of $x$ under the action of all automorphisms of $H$ is exactly $x^G=\{2,5\}$.  The stabilizer $G_x$ is the set of automorphisms of $H$ that fix the vertex $x$.  If an automorphism fixes 2, it must fix 5.  It can swap 1 and 3 (or fix them pointwise), and it can swap 4 and 6 (or fix them pointwise).  The number of elements in $G_x$ is thus $2 \times 2=4$.  Thus, $|G|=2 \times 4=8$.  Alternatively, you can take $x$ to be the vertex 1, say.  In this case $|G_x|=2, |x^G|=4$, whence $|G|=8$. In other words, if we know $|x^G|$ and $|G_x|$ for some $x \in X$, then we can use that information to find $|G|$.

In addition to the number of automorphisms, we are often interested in exactly which group $G$ is.  Since $ab \ne ba$, $G$ is nonabelian.  It can be shown (by group theory) that there are exactly two nonisomorphic groups of order 8 that are not abelian, namely the dihedral group $D_8$ of symmetries of a square, and the quaternion group.  Since the number of elements of order 2 in the quaternion group is only 1, whereas our $G$ has at least two elements of order 2 (namely, the elements $a,b$), it follows that $G$ cannot be the quaternion group and hence $G \cong D_8$.

Comment: Good point, only thing is that is not so clear why there are only 8 elements, can you explain please?:)

Comment: @RicPed: I've explained this now.

Comment: Thank you, i was aware of the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the problem is how to work with graphs, because I haven't encountered until now:)

Comment: @RicPed: You could work through one of the graph theory texts that you find suits your taste; solve the exercises there.  There are also books in algebraic graph theory that discuss automorphisms of graphs in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what's a graph homomorphism? In my definition, it's a map $f: G\to H$ (by which I mean it sends vertices to vertices *and* edges to edges) such that, if $(a,b)$ is an edge in $G$, then $(f(a),f(b))$ is an edge in $H$.

First of all, you should convince yourself that it's enough to work out where the vertices go: if $f: H\to H$ is an automorphism and you know what $f(a)$ is for all vertices $a$ in $H$, you know where all the edges are. (Why is this?) Having done this, you *can* just specify automorphisms as permutations in $S_6$ like you've been doing.

Secondly, to answer you rather obliquely: the two reflections and one point rotation you've found are automorphisms; but are there more? (What about the map given by $(1\; 3)$? What about the identity map? Importantly, automorphisms form a group; what group is it?) If you apply the permutation $f = (2\;5)$, the edge between $1$ and $2$ will turn into an edge appearing between $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 5$, which you don't want, so this doesn't give you an automorphism.

Comment: By the way, if you're just looking for the *number of elements* in Aut(H), it might be a little easier to apply the orbit-stabiliser theorem. But I think this is good practice too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't know the orbit stabilizer theorem and don't know enough group theory to understand it I am afraid. Thanks for pointing out the identity, $(1\ 3)$ and $(4\ 6)$ maps, I missed those. Am I right in assuming that $\operatorname{Aut}(H) \subset S_6$ because all automorphisms in the end just rearrange the nodes. Then because $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is a subgroup of $S_6$ (which has 720 elements) and thus $(no. of elements \operatorname{Aut}(H)|720$. This is now the case as I have so far found 6 elements and $6|720$. Can I reasonable prove there are no others? Thanks

Comment: It's definitely not the case that there are no others. (For a group-theoretic reason: the group {identity, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\sigma_3$} is a subgroup of Aut(H), so Aut(H) must have size divisible by 4. Practically: try multiplying (1 3) by $\sigma_2$ and see whether you get anything new - I suspect you will.) When you think you're done, try to prove there's nothing else that could possibly happen. (Here's a purely combinatorial answer: let $f$ be an automorphism of $H$. How many choices are there for $f(1)$? How many choices are there for $f(2)$ if you know $f(1)$? etc.)

Comment: Hey thanks again for your answer, I like the argument why 6 can never be the answer! However, when I do $\sigma_2 (1\ 3)$ I get $(1\ 4)(2\ 5)(3\ 6)(1\ 3) = \sigma_3$ as defined above, and also for $(1\ 3)\sigma_2$. I want to thank you for your help and apologize that I find it hard to follow, I've been doing group theory now for 3 weeks and whenever I think I have a good grasp of what's going on I find a question that I can't wrap my head around :)

Comment: Are you sure? I get (1 6 3 4)(2 5), which isn't the same as $\sigma_3$. (Alternative 1: draw pictures and do this multiplication geometrically. Alternative 2: notice that the identity and your $\sigma$s are all *rigid motions*, whereas my (1 3) is a 'twist', as it flips one leg and leaves the other alone. Doing a rigid motion followed by a twist can't give you a rigid motion. Alternative 3 (a translation of 2): call the group of size 4 I mentioned "G". Then (1 3) and the identity are in different cosets (of G in Aut(H)), so $\sigma_2(1\;3) = \sigma_3$ (and so $G(1\;3)=G$) is impossible.)

Comment: (By the way: don't worry about it too much. Groups are weird. No matter how much you think you understand them, someone else can prove to you that you don't. :))